# c# public string pass into function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the code below and am trying to access the 'text' string in the lnkSave_Click function, but text doesn't seem accesible from lnkSave_Click function, it always seems empty.

```
private string _text = "";
    public string text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
             text = "Hello World!";
            }
        }

protected void lnkSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (text == "Hello World!")
            {
            ... do things..
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it's empty it **is** accessible. The reason why it's always empty is that it's a field. Every object in an ASP.NET page is disposed at the end of the life-cycle. So it'll be initialized with `""` on every postback.

You could use the ViewState to persist the value:

```
public string text
{
    get { if(ViewState["text"]==null)ViewState["text"]=""; return (String)ViewState["text"]; }
    set { ViewState["text"] = value; }
}
```

[**Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)